# JAXB : How to manipuulate the Data during Unmarshalling process

Tags: java, jaxb2

**I am using jaxb for the Unmarshalling Process**

**This is my Request**

```
<kiran acct = "1234567" />

package com;
@XmlRootElement(name = "kiran")
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
public class CustAcct {

    @XmlAttribute
    private String acct;

    public CustAcct() {

        super();
    }

    public String getAcct() {
        System.out.println("The New Getter Method of Account is called");
        return acct;
    }

    public void setAcct(String s) {
        System.out.println("The New Setter Method of Account  is called");
        acct = s;
    }

}
```

**This is the way Jersey (Restful Framework ) automatically binds the data with JAXB**

```
public class HelloService {

    @POST
    @Produces("application/text")
    public String sayPlainTextHello(CustAcct custdata) {

        System.out.println("The New Account is " + custdata.getAcct());
        return "Hi";
    }

}
```

Here my question is that , **why the Setter Method setAcct is not getting called in this case** ??

I mean why the Line "The New Setter Method of Account  is called" isn't being printed , and where as the Line inside the getMethod is geting called (The New Getter Method of Account is called)

**Basically I want to Manupulate  Data to an Attribute which is sent in the Request XML .**

is there any call back method by which i can control the way Data is being Set ??

Thanks in advance .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**why the Setter Method setAcct is not getting called in this case ??**

Because you set the access type to field: `@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)`. Change it to `@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.PROPERTY)`

[XmlAccessType](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/xml/bind/annotation/XmlAccessType.html) javadoc.

**is there any call back method by which i can control the way Data is being Set ??**

Yes. You have complete control on the marshall/unmarshall process when you use [adapters](http://blog.bdoughan.com/2010/07/xmladapter-jaxbs-secret-weapon.html).